# How to remove extra whitespaces after paragraphs when adding Arabic text in IEEE template?

Tags: vertical-spacing

I am using `\raggedbottom` for my document. For some reason, when I add Arabic text between English text, it thinks that there isn't enough space in the end so it moves the text to another page.

I tried the following:

- Scoping the paragraph within a no page break

  ````
    {\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
     \vtop\bgroup}
    {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
     \prevdepth=\tpd}```
  ````
- Adding `\nolinebreak`
- Scoping the paragraph within a `\minipage`

But none of them worked. The paragraphs stay the same.

[image]

Here is the code I have

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\raggedbottom  
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]
et netus et malesuada fames \RL{العربية} ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada famesc turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum

\begin{itemize}
    \item {\lipsum[1][1]}
    \item {\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    \item {\lipsum[1][1]}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Related Work}
\label{sec:relatedwork}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Methodology}
\label{sec:methodology}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, just changing `\RL{العربية}` to `\<العربية>` which is [the other way of writing Arabic text between English text](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Arabic) solves this issue. This should be applied to all the Arabic text in the document.

[image]